# External Access to localhost Xampp files

Tags: networking, xampp, portforwarding

I am using no-ip for generating a domain name .

I have already set-up port-forwarding(**I am using D-link**)
and it is successfully forwarding to localhost.(`http://localhost`)

But I would want it to forward to a file in htdocs in xampp folder.
something like `http://localhost/folder/file.php`

how to configure this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You need this to be your index file in your htdocs folder.

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/folder/file.php');
    exit;
?>
```